# How to update Reagent vector in an atom

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent

I've got a Reagent atom:

```
(defonce order (r/atom {:firstName "" :lastName "" :toppings [] }))
```

I want to add toppings to the `:toppings` vector.  I have tried many variations on:

`(swap! (:toppings order) conj "Pepperoni")`  which gives me: `Uncaught Error: No protocol method ISwap.-swap! defined for type null:`

`(swap! order :toppings "Pepperoni")` sort of works, but just updates order, not the `:toppings` vector.  When I deref `order`, I just get the latest value.

What is the right way to add (and remove) values to my `:toppings` vector?

Comment: All of the answers below are valuable.  I accepted the answer that most directly answers the question, but the others offer more insight into how to work with atoms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update toppings with:

```
(swap! order update :toppings conj "Pepperoni")
```

Answer (score 6):

Just to explain a little more, when you do `(swap! (:toppings order) ...)`, you are retrieving the `:toppings` key from `order`, which would make sense if it were a map, but it's an atom, so `(:toppings order)` returns `nil`.

The first argument to `swap!` should always be an atom (`Reagent` atoms work the same way).  The second argument should be a function which takes the content of the atom as its first argument.  Then, you can optionally provide more arguments that will be passed to the function argument.

Instead of minhtuannguyen's answer, you could do the following:

```
(swap! order
  (fn a [m]
    (update m :toppings
      (fn b [t]
        (conj t "Pepperoni")))))
```

`fn a` receives the map inside the atom, binds it to `m`, then updates it and returns a new map, which becomes the new value of the atom.

If you wanted to, you could redefine `fn a` to take a second argument:

```
(swap! order
  (fn a [m the-key]
    (update m the-key
      (fn b [t]
        (conj t "Pepperoni"))))
  :toppings)
```

`:toppings` is now being passed as the second argument to `fn a`, and then passed to `update` inside of `fn a`.  We could do the same to the third argument to `update`:

```
(swap! order
  (fn a [m the-key the-fn]
    (update m the-key the-fn))
  :toppings
  (fn b [t]
    (conj t "Pepperoni")))
```

Now `update` has the same signature as `fn a`, so we no longer need `fn a` at all.  We can simply provide `update` directly in place of `fn a`:

```
(swap! order update :toppings
  (fn b [t]
    (conj t "Pepperoni")))
```

But we can keep going, because `update` also accepts more arguments which it then passes to the function provided to it.  We could rewrite `fn b` to take another argument:

```
(swap! order update :toppings
  (fn b [t the-topping]
    (conj t the-topping))
  "Pepperoni"))
```

Once again, `conj` has the same signature as `fn b`, so `fn b` is redundant, and we can just use `conj` in its place:

```
(swap! order update :toppings conj "Pepperoni")
```

Thus, we end up with minhtuannguyen's answer.

Answer (score 5):

I would turn `toppings` into a set. I don't think you want duplicate toppings in the collection, so a set is appropriate:

```
(defonce order (r/atom {:first-name "" :last-name "" :toppings #{}})) ; #{} instead of []
```

Then you can still [`conj`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/conj) as stated in the other answer:

```
(swap! order update :toppings conj "Pepperoni")
```

but you can also [`disj`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/disj):

```
(swap! order update :toppings disj "Pepperoni")
```

Comment: What if someone wants to double the amount of pepperoni? ;-)

Comment: @NathanDavis Fair enough. :) Use a hash-map from topping name to quantity. E.g. `{"pepperoni" 2}`. To increase `(update-in order [:toppings "pepperoni"] inc)` or `dec` to decrease. Perhaps remove an entry when the value is 0.